# Java: errors in shaping Mongolian glyphs

Tags: java, swing, javafx, opentype

Context: Java 11, JavaFx 11 (where applicable), Linux Mint 19.3, Eclipse 2020.06. Java apps run as desktop applications.

Background: The Mongolian script is considered "complex" and, to be shaped correctly, requires OpenType tables as `isol`, `init`, `medi`, `fina`, `rlig` in the font(s) implementing it.

I am trying to insert Mongolian strings in Java UI and I am having unexpected results both with Swing and with JavaFX.

Basically, if a Mongolian string like "ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ" is inserted in a Swing `JLabel` or in an Fx `Label` alone, it is rendered without any shaping (more or less as in "ᠪ ᠠ ᠢ ᠨ ᠠ"), while if a string in another "complex" string is added in the same label, say "अनुच्छेद ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ" or "ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ अनुच्छेद", then it is rendered correctly.

Furthermore, I noticed that in Swing, either a Devanāgarī or an Arabic string turn on the correct shaping, while in JavaFx a Devanāgarī addition does the job but an Arabic addition does not.

Of course, I cannot add arbitrary strings just to turn the correct shaping on. Am I forgetting some important initialisation or is the Java shaping tier of the font stack broken? (I suppose it is HarfBuzz, which usually works quite well...).

Thanks for any suggestion!

A Swing minimal example, which comments showing which strings are rendered correctly and which are not:

```
package com.vistamaresoft.swingtest;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Main
{
    private         JFrame      frame;
    private static  Main        window;

    public Main()
    {
        frame   = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Mongolian Swing Test");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 200);
        //Set up the GUI.
        JPanel      panel       = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JLabel      label       = new JLabel("ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ");         // NOT CORRECT
        panel.add(label);
        label                   = new JLabel("Abc ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ");     // NOT CORRECT
        panel.add(label);
        label                   = new JLabel("ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ  كتاب ");  // CORRECT
        panel.add(label);
        label                   = new JLabel("كتاب ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ");        // CORRECT
        panel.add(label);
        label                   = new JLabel("ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ अनुच्छेद");        // CORRECT
        panel.add(label);
        label                   = new JLabel("अनुच्छेद ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ");        // CORRECT
        panel.add(label);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        window = new Main();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

A JavaFx minimal example. Note that the `WebView` is not any better than a `Label` and that copy and pasting a label text into the HTML input field yields the same results:

```
package com.vistamaresoft.fxtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main
{
    static final String html    = 
    "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\"\n\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\n" + 
    "<html>\n<body>\n" +
    "<p style='font-size: 18pt;'>Sample text: ᠴᠣᠴᠡᠭ᠎ᠠ</p>" +        // NOT CORRECT!
    "<p style='font-size: 18pt;'>ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ كتاب </p>" +                // NOT CORRECT!
    "<p style='font-size: 18pt;'>अनुच्छेद ᠴᠣᠴᠡᠭ᠎ᠠ</p>" +                // CORRECT!
    "<p><input type='text' name='title' size='20' maxlength='50' style='font-size: 18pt;' /></p>" +
    "</body></html>\n";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(MainApp.class, args);
    }

    public static class MainApp extends Application
    {
        @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
        {
            WebView webView = new WebView();
            webView.getEngine().loadContent(html);
            Label   lab1    = new Label("ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ");      // NOT CORRECT
            lab1.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt;");
            Label   lab2    = new Label("ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ كتاب"); // NOT CORRECT
            lab2.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt;");
            Label   lab3    = new Label("كتاب ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ"); // NOT CORRECT
            lab3.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt;");
            Label   lab4    = new Label("ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ अनुच्छेद"); // CORRECT
            lab4.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt;");
            Label   lab5    = new Label("अनुच्छेद ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ"); // CORRECT
            lab5.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24pt;");
    
            VBox    vBox    = new VBox(webView, lab1, lab2, lab3, lab4, lab5);
            Scene   scene   = new Scene(vBox, 800, 600);
    
            primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Mongolian Test");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:

These issues have been filed as bugs by the Java bug database:

1. the AWT bug: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8252091
2. the JavaFx bug: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8252220

Comment: Have you tried using unicode values, for example \u1800 instead of _mongolian birga_? Have you tried using HTML, for example `new JLabel("<html>...)` ?

Comment: @Abra Thanks for the quick reply. Using the Unicode code points instead of actual characters makes no difference neither in Swing nor in JavaFx. Embedding HTML in Swing controls yields the same results and with JavaFx does not seems to be supported, as one can see the HTML tags spelled out in full (outside of `WebView`, I mean).

Comment: I forgot to add that with Java-gnome, the Mongolian strings are shaped and laid out correctly. Unfortunately, it is not a viable solution, as it is not portable outside Linux/Unix.

Comment: After a couple of hours of debugging into JDK, there seem to be an error in a rather obscure source file for the `sun.font.FontUtilies` class: the `public static boolean isComplexCharCode(int code)` method fails to recognise the Mongolian code point range (0x1800 - 0x18FF) as complex character codes. The source file is in the `src/java.desktop/share/classes/sun/font/` dir of the OpenJDK repository. As simply notifying a new issue to the OpenJDK issue tracker requires qualifications and permissions I do not have, I cannot see what to do next...

Comment: You can edit the source code of class `FontUtilities`, compile it and paste it into the relevant JAR file using a utility like [WinRAR](https://www.win-rar.com/start.html?&L=0).

Comment: @Abra Yes, I started to do that, but 1) this file is an internal class which references several other internal non-exported packages and some "not found" other classes (actually found in quite unrelated other directories), so the compiling is a trial and error guess process and ...

Comment: ...2) there is no "relevant JAR file": the OpenJDK 11 installed on my Linux Mint only have one quite small (106 kB) `jrt-fs.jar` which seems to contain only code to access the "real" Java libraries in the form of "*.jmod" files I have no idea how to manage; there is a "jmod" executable in the Java bins, which sounds like a tool to manage them: another trial and error process. All of this just to change 1 byte of one integer value (0x17FF => 0x18FF). I hope sooner or later I'll find someone with the permissions to post a patch to the Java code base... :(

Comment: Just to summarise, I have notified a user-submitted bug for AWT/Swing to the Java bug tracker which has been accepted today. So, this is officially a bug. I also have submitted another bug relative to JavaFX, but the evaluation process is not completed yet.

Comment: Good luck with that. I posted [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8242616) a few months ago. I'm sure it may **never** be resolved.

Comment: Which Java 11? Oracle's Java is still on 8 (u261), and openJDK is on 14, so which flavour of Java is this? and if it's openJDK, what does v14 do?

Comment: 11 is still the LTS version for OpenJDK, so I stick to it for all my development. I tried OpenJDK 14 in a Win10 VM and it does exactly the same. Incidentally, the openjfx team did accept my second bug report (the one for JavaFx), so now both bugs are "official".

Comment: If they are officially accepted bugs, can you please write an answer to your own question that explains that there _is_ no solution because this is a bug in the JDK,, with the links to those bugs, so that you can accept that answer and future visitors don't need to trawl a comment section on an unanswered question? There is now an answer: this is a known bug, see the links for more information. SO only works because questions get answers, even if those answers are "you're out of luck, here's why: ..." =)